# Django RQ ModuleNotFoundError xxx is not a package

Tags: python, django, rq

I'm using django rq for some long running task, which I would like to provide some feedback about its progress. I hence created a function which is enqueued as a new task and set some model's attribute and save them.

Here is a simplified view:

```
class Status(models.Model):
  progress_a = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class MyObject(models.Model):
    status = models.OneToOneField(Status)

    @django_rq.job('low-short')
    def set_status(self, progress_name, progress):
        setattr(self.status, progress_name, progress)
        self.status.save()

   def set_status_a(self, progress):
        self.set_status.delay(self=self, progress_name="progress_a", progress=progress)

@django_rq.job('default')
def long_running_job():
    my_instance.set_status_a(100)
```

Now, executing this give me the following output :

```
2022-05-16 15:50:03 app-85c8459c79-mrkhg rq.worker[1] INFO low-short: api.models.MyObject.set_status(progress=0, progress_name='progress_a', self=<MyObject: MyObject object (129)>) (c13480ca-a25b-4463-af9a-a0a0dd67de61)
2022-05-16 15:50:03 app-85c8459c79-mrkhg root[41] WARNING Import error for 'api.models.MyObject'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/utils.py", line 141, in import_attribute
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 981, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api.models.MyObject'; 'api.models' is not a package
```

- **api** is a package
- **api.models** a module
- **models.MyObject** a class.

I don't get why it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?
*long_running_job* starts as a job flawlessly.

*Note:* when removing **self=self**, it complains about missing self.

**Update**

Here is the workaround I use to make it work:

```
# The Method from the class call a simple function
def set_status_a(self, progress):
  set_status_a(obj_id=self.id, progress_name="progress_a", progress=progress)
```

```
# set_status_a call another function as a job
def set_status_a(obj_id, progress):
    _set_status_a(obj_id, progress)
```

```
# _set_status_a make the change by retrieving the object
@django_rq.job('default')
def _set_status_a(obj_id, progress):
    my_obj = MyObject.objects.get(id=obj_id)
    my_obj.status = progress
    my_obj.save()
```

Comment: @daufinsysd: did you solve this issue?

Comment: Not really, I found a workaround which consists of calling the queued function from an intermediate one (not a method):
`@django_rq.job('default')
def my_job(obj_id, data):
  ...

def intermediate_function(obj_id, data):
  my_job(obj_id, data)

def models_function(self, data):
  my_function(self.id, data)`

obj_id is the id of the object which has the status update. Not beautiful but it works.

Comment: I updated the description since the response isn't readable @huyxdong

Comment: @daufinsysd: thank you for your info. I found that it is just a WARNING and the code still runs as expected. Just ignore that if you want.